# Error "enumeration cannot be a template" ¿Seguro?

Tags: c++, enum, abogado-del-lenguaje

Cuando intento crear un enumerado plantilla, me surge el error "enumeration cannot be a template":

```
// error: enumeration cannot be a template
template <typename T> // Enumerado clásico
enum E1 : T { A, B, C };

// error: enumeration cannot be a template
template <typename T> // Clase enumerado 
enum class E2 : T { A, B, C };
```

La posibilidad de especificar el tipo del enumerado está disponible desde C++11, así que pensé que podría tener sentido la existencia de enumerados plantilla, pero el compilador indica **explícitamente** que está prohibido; no he podido encontrar en el estándar dónde está definida esa prohibición.

Sin embargo, si anidamos el enumerado en un objeto, sí que podemos crear enumerados plantilla:

```
template <typename T>
class EC
{
    enum class Enumerado : T { A, B, C };
public:
    Enumerado funcion() { return {}; }
};

template <typename T>
class E
{
    enum Enumerado : T { A, B, C };
public:
    Enumerado funcion() { return {}; }
};

template <typename T>
std::string tipo(const T&) { return {typeid(T).name()}; }

template <typename T>
std::string tipo_subyacente(const T&) { return {typeid(std::underlying_type_t<T>).name()}; }

int main()
{
    EC<int> eci;
    EC<long> ecs;
    E<int> ei;
    E<long> es;

    auto muestra = [](auto v) { std::cout << "Tipo: " << tipo(v) << " tipo subyacente: " << tipo_subyacente(v) << '\n'; };

    muestra(eci.funcion());
    muestra(ecs.funcion());
    muestra(ei.funcion());
    muestra(es.funcion());

    return 0;
}
```

El código anterior muestra [la siguiente salida](https://tio.run/##rVLBboMwDD2Tr7A6aYWqa9cegSF1FX/AbZuqNGRVJAiIJJOqim9nJtCWqqLaYbf4@T0/2zEryxeWUXlomichWWZSDqEolK44zSNyxRAR8jBE9LHkO11RoVVEiOZ5mVHd45LmHJKIYGmlIN6SE3G4NDn0AD55RdMCfEjgBJs5vM9hC3VASrPPBPOJc@V8G8lEIV0PmRXXppJwqgOoCdIf@15s/89wORux7HxW9waP@H2f63vVbDmiUzr1/e43QIuycFkhlYbk2WunPbfbKkTqJt6i1bkeVqzJHyvulNkfKeNS84fFrc7IlFfZEbW77iDCJLo1FVJDTgWus60Rb0MEIuBMBDbKCjwrDFUb9jmbOmcwQRxqdAG54dgmhTf4@HIt8tN@ke2DFUZDGMIkwQl8mLRvux6ktLAN4DrZgDKct2NPP@U0sH/n9J4u9ru43IUXDBNqJDEmuOXjQV1S8couwPc3Q0G8HqB4F@d/eMX1Ns0v):

> ```
> Tipo: N2ECIiE9EnumeradoE tipo subyacente: i
> Tipo: N2ECIlE9EnumeradoE tipo subyacente: l
> Tipo: N1EIiE9EnumeradoE tipo subyacente: i
> Tipo: N1EIlE9EnumeradoE tipo subyacente: l
> ```

Por lo que podemos ver, que sí se puede hacer que un enumerado sea plantilla (al menos parte de una). ¿En qué parte del estándar está explicitado que los enumerados no pueden ser plantillas? ¿Cuál es la lógica tras esta decisión?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/n4849.pdf seccion 13.1 dice que una plantilla define una familia de clases, funciones, o variables, un alias por un familia de tipos, o un concepto. Aparentemente, ¿un enumeracíon no sea ninguno de estos, aún que és un tipo?

> A template defines a family of classes, functions, or variables, an alias for a family of types, or a concept.

Basado en este pregunta en Stack Overflow en inglés: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38280474/5445670.